# Interpretation of Sura 19 Verse 24

Tags: quran, tafseer

In Sura 19, Verse 24, mention is made that Jibrail AS calls upon Mariam AS from **below her**.
[image]

Sahih International translates this as ***But he called her from below her, "Do not grieve; your Lord has provided beneath you a stream.***

My question is: why is it said **below her** ? What is the reason for precising that Jibrail AS was below ?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the exegetes claim that the speaker here is Gabriel (عليه السلام), however some claim that he is Jesus (عليه السلام). If it is Gabriel then it is said because Mary (عليه السلام) was at a hill and the angel was in the valley beneath her. Refer to Tafsirs e.g. [Ibn Kathir](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura19-aya24.html#katheer) etc.

Comment: If it is Gabriel AS, he could have been in front of Mariam AS. Was Gabriel AS beneath because Allah didn't want him to see Mariam AS delivering ? Is there anything mentioned concerning this ?